# How to remove label names in Corrplot

Tags: r, visualization, r-corrplot

I am trying to plot a visualization using Corrplot in R. I have several variables in my data frame but when I try to plot the chart it shows as a very shabby visualization. I am not sure how do I remove the names of the variables in the matrix and only represent them by numbers. I used a normal code to plot the chart. Please excuse my lack of awareness over here, I am very new to R and learning to know more.

```
Library(corrplot)
m <- cor(df)
corrplot(m, method = "circle")
```

[My chart is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjrNn.png)

Comment: Thanks @G5W! this works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an input to `corrplot` specifically to control this. Just use

```
corrplot(m, method = "circle", tl.pos='n')
```